# Firebase hosting: The remote web server hosts what may be a publicly accessible .bash_history file

Tags: firebase-hosting

We host our website on firebase. We fail a security check due to the following reason:

The remote web server hosts publicly available files whose contents may be indicative of a typical bash history. Such files may contain sensitive information that should not be disclosed to the public.

The following .bash_history files are available on the remote server : - /.bash_history Note, this file is being flagged because you have set your scan to 'Paranoid'. The contents of the detected file has not been inspected to see if it contains any of the common Linux commands one might expect to see in a typical .bash_history file. - /cgi-bin/.bash_history Note, this file is being flagged because you have set your scan to 'Paranoid'. The contents of the detected file has not been inspected to see if it contains any of the common Linux commands one might expect to see in a typical .bash_history file. - /scripts/.bash_history Note, this file is being flagged because you have set your scan to 'Paranoid'. The contents of the detected file has not been inspected to see if it contains any of the common Linux commands one might expect to see in a typical .bash_history file.

The problem is that we don't have an easy way to get access to the hosting machine and delete these files.

Anybody knows how it can be solved?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Firebase Hosting, you should check the directory (usually `public`) that you are uploading via the `firebase deploy` command.  Hosting serves only those files (plus a couple of auto-generated ones under the reserved `__/` path for auto-configuration).

If you have a `.bash_history`, `cgi-bin/.bash_history` or `scripts/.bash_history` in that public directory, then it will be uploaded to and served by Hosting.  There are no automatically served files with those name.

You can check your public directory, and update the list of files to ignore on the next deploy using the firebase.json file (see [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#specify-files-to-deply)).  You can also download all the files that Firebase Hosting is serving for you using [this script](https://gist.github.com/mbleigh/9c8680cf319ace2f506f57380da66e7d).